# Counterexample for $(A \times B) \cup (C \times D) \subset (A \cup C) \times (B \cup D)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For sets A, B, D, C:

$(A \times B) \cup (C \times D) \subset (A \cup C) \times (B \cup D)$

Try to give a counterexample where this statement doesn't hold true. I know an empty set could be a valid counterexample. But how exactly?

Comment: Do you   want proper inclusion?

Comment: @DavidMitra Probably not

Comment: The usual modern usage is that $X\subset Y\iff (X=Y\lor X\subsetneqq Y).$ On the other hand, if $C=D=\emptyset$ then your RHS and LHS are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\subset$ stands for "is a subset of" then no counterexample exists.

If $\subset$ stands for "is a proper subset of" then a counterexample is provided if we take $A=C$ and $B=D$.

Comment: I think $\subset$ stands for "is proper subset of". Could you elaborate on the provided solution with a practical example, please?

Comment: If you take e.g. $A=C=X$ and $B=D=Y$ then $A\cup C=X$ and $B\cup D=Y$ so that: $$(A\times B)\cup(C\times D)=(X\times Y)\cup(X\times Y)=X\times Y=(A\cup C)\times(B\cup D)$$If you want a more practical solution then just substitute some sets for $X$ and $Y$ that are familiar to you. E.g. $X=\mathbb R$ and $Y=\{3,5\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since$$(x,\,y)\in(A\times B)\cup(C\times D)\implies (x\in A\land y\in B)\lor(x\in C\land y\in D)\\\implies (x\in A\lor x\in C)\land(y\in B\lor y\in D)\implies(x,\,y)\in(A\cup C)\times(B\cup D),$$we have $(A\times B)\cup(C\times D)\subseteq(A\cup C)\times(B\cup D)$. A counterexample to $\subsetneq$ requires the sets to be equal, e.g. with $A=C,\,B=D$.

Answer (score 0):

In order the inclusion to be false in some case , the corresponding conditional ( worded in terms of membership relation) has to be false as well in that case.

So, if there is no possible situation in which the corresponding conditional is false, then, there is no counterexample to the original inclusion statement.

But the truth table ( of the corresponding conditional)  shows there is no possible ( consistent) situation in which we could be both (1) in the (unique)  case where the consequent is false and (2) in a ( possible) case where the antecedent is true.

Indeed, ***consider simultaneously  the (unique) "false-consequent-case" and any posssible " true-antecedent-case" , you will always find ( at least) a column in which the two cases contradict.***

So , there is no truth assignment that makes the conditional false, and consequently, there is no counterexample to the original inclusion.

[image]